Gauge invariance in systems with multiple correlated fermions
Photons are associated with the covariant derivative $D_\mu(x) = \partial_\mu + i e A_\mu(x)$ that make equations with a fermion field $\psi_\alpha(x)$ invariant under gauge transformations $\psi(x) \rightarrow exp(i \sigma(x)) \psi(x)$ $A_\mu(x) \rightarrow A_\mu(x) - 1/e \partial_\mu \sigma(x)$.
Consider a 2-fermion field $\psi_{\alpha,\beta}(x,y)$ that corresponds to the two electrons in helium atom. In principle, one can consider gauge transformations of the form $\psi(x,y) \rightarrow exp(i \rho(x,y)) \psi(x,y)$.
Q: why there is no gauge field that corresponds to these transformations?
EDIT Dec 18 2024
Remark 2: We may consider the space $(x,y)$ as a product manifold $M\times M$. Then the covariant derivative on this product manifold indeed takes the form $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu} + A_\mu(x,y), \frac{\partial}{\partial y_\mu} + B_\mu(x,y) )$ with two independent fields $A_\mu(x,y), B_\mu(x,y)$. The answers and comments below suggest that we can only consider the derivatives of the form $( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu} + A_\mu(x), \frac{\partial}{\partial y_\mu} + A_\mu(y)$ with field of one variable $A_\mu(x)$. This is a more restricted notion of gauge transformation.
Q: does it follow from QFT( path integral or canonical quantizations) that this should be the case?
EDIT Dec 20,2024
In the book Bethe, Salpeter "Quantum mechanics of one and two electron atoms", the following Bethe-Salpeter equation is discussed
\begin{equation}
(i\hat{D}(x)+m_1)(i\hat{D}(y)+m_2)\psi(x,y) = \int K(x,y,u,v) \psi(u,v)
\end{equation}
This equation supports the more restrictive notion of gauge transform( it is invariant under more restricted transform, but not invariant under the more general one). But we know very well that Bethe-Salpeter equation is not included in the partition function formulation.  It also does not follow from the second quantized Schrodinger equation in operator quantization. It has to be imposed as additional principle.
Q3: How far can this be generalized if we include more multiparticle fermion wavefunctions?
E.g. one can consider the following n-particle fermion equation
\begin{equation}
(i\hat{D}(x_1)+m_1)...(i\hat{D}(x_n)+m_n)\psi(x_1,...,x_n) = \int K(x_1,....,x_n,y_1,...,y_n)\psi(y_1,...,y_n)
\end{equation}
with the perturbative kernel $K_n$. But what is the physical meaning of it? In the formal ladder expansion, we see at least some terms that come from feynman diagrams, so clearly there is some double counting going on.

Explain your question?

What is a "2 fermion field"?

A wavefunction isn't a field. The space of two fermion states is a subspace of the Fock space, which is the space of states of the fermion field. So (assuming no quantum anomalies, which is an ok assumption in QED) the action of the field being gauge invariant implies observables constructed out of the field are gauge invariant, which includes observables involving 2 fermion processes. You don't need a different gauge transformation for 1 particle, 2 particles, etc.

It seems that you are suggesting that what makes physical sense is the state of the form $\int dp_1\ dp_2\ \phi_{s_1,s_2}(\vec{p}_1,\vec{p}_2) a^+(\vec{p}_1)a^+(\vec{p_2})|0>$ and not the relativistic joint wave function $\psi(x,y)$. Did I understand you correctly?

The notion of a "fermion field" on which a gauge transformation can be applied is represented by a field operator. Field operators are used to model a theory. It is not a state of one fermion.
On the other hand, the notion of a "2-fermion field" corresponds to a state that consists of two fermions. It can be represented as a two-fermion wave functions in terms of a superposition of tensor products of single-fermion wave functions. To perform a gauge transformations on such a wave function you need to apply the gauge transformation on each of the two single-fermion wave functions in the state.

I like that this answer distinguishes fields and wavefunctions, which I think is very relevant here, but I don't understand: "Gauge transformations are not applied to wave functions." See, eg, https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qm/Quantum/node35.html.

@Andrew, thanks for the clarification.

It seems that you are suggesting that the allowed gauge transformations are of the form $\psi(x,y) \rightarrow exp(i\sigma_1(x))\psi(x,y)$ and $\psi(x,y) \rightarrow exp(i\sigma_2(y))\psi(x,y)$, but the transformations $\psi(x,y) \rightarrow exp(i\rho(x,y))\psi(x,y)$ are not allowed?

Unless you can express the last one in terms of the previous ones.

@flippiefanus There is a problem with this suggestion. If you think that $exp(i\sigma_1(x))$ corresponds to the gauge transform that corrsponds to the electron-nucleus interaction, and the same for $exp(i\sigma_2(y))$, then there should be a term for $exp(i\sigma_3(x-y))$ because there is also the field for the interaction of the two electrons.

I believe that a gauge field in a physical system like helium is not exactly zero but rather negligibly small. The two-fermion field represents an "information exchange system." However, a field composed of only two fermions is a significant simplification of reality. In such a simplified model, the necessity of an additional gauge field can often be ignored.
If we instead consider a real system composed of nearly infinite number of fermion fields, we eventually encounter an information capacity limit. This limit manifests in fundamental constraints such as the speed of light and the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.
From this perspective, I would argue that a multi-fermion field can itself be viewed as a mathematical object or gauge field. Conversely, even a single-fermion field could be transformed into a more comprehensive physical description by incorporating "information from the past." Such an approach could provide a deeper understanding of the interplay between locality, entanglement, and gauge invariance in quantum systems.
PS: My answer is based on logic and does not necessarily correspond to the current view of physics.

The question is how to test experimentally the effects of such 2-photon fields. Here is a calculation for Helium  https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.00806 . How to modify it to include the 2-photon fields? Then compare with the experimental results https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.263002

In standard physics, there is no gauge field that supports transformations of the form
ψ(x,y)→exp(iρ(x,y))ψ(x,y),
because such transformations depend not only on a single point x, but also on another point y. Classical gauge fields like Aµ (x,y) are only defined locally at a single point x. There is no mathematical structure in the standard theory that explicitly describes the interaction between two points x and y.
One possible explanation is that standard gauge theories are based on locally defined fields that only account for the immediate present at a specific point. If one considers the possibility that information from the past fundamentally persists into the present, one could imagine an extended field Aµ (x,y) that describes the relationship between a point x in the present and a point y in the past.
Role of an extended gauge field:
•   The parameter ρ(x,y), which governs the transformation, could be interpreted as a function that establishes a connection between the states at x and y.
•   A corresponding gauge field Aµ (x,y) would then act as a generalized coupling that is not merely local but instead links states across different regions of space-time.
Why does such a field not exist in standard physics?
In standard physics, the influence of the past on the present is typically accounted for indirectly, for example, through boundary conditions or propagators. An explicit field coupling x and y directly would require an extension of the current framework. Such fields could be developed within a broader context that transcends the local description of standard theories and postulates a deeper connection between space, time, and preserved information.
Conclusion:
The absence of such a gauge field in standard physics reflects the local symmetry constraints of existing models. An extension that explicitly incorporates the relationships between the present and the past could offer a novel perspective, where fields like Aµ (x,y) play a central role. This approach might be particularly relevant for describing systems such as the helium atom or, more generally, multi-particle systems.

Thanks for your answer. This is more or less how I understand the issue. Indeed, the field has to do with requirement of locality( in fact, this is how Maxwell introduced it: he wanted local theory, and for this we need field degrees of freedom). The requirement that $A_\mu(x,y)$ and similar higher fields does not follow from any other basic principles of quantum theory. I would like to clarify if it is exactly zero or it is just small ( say, of order "\alpha^2$) in physical systems such as helium. The issue seems to be deep as it pertains to notions of locality, entanglement,gauge invariance
